# How do you compare music data

Tags: java, audio

I want to write an app to rename sort and organize my music library (mp3's, wav's, flac's).  I wanted to take a portion of the song, say the first minutes, and compare that to a database and then retrieve the song name and tag information.  I have heard that you can do this with last.fm but a look through their api info didn't help.  My question is, what is this called so i can google it better? nothing I am trying is helping much.  This would be similar to the shazam android app. My preferred language would be Java, so I can run it on a few operating systems easier, but that might be subject to change depending on how I can do it.

Comment: Where are you going to get the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I don't know if you need a practical or a technical answer.

Practically the best music database out there is MusicBrainz.

They have developed a fingerprinting technology that calculats what they I think call PUIDs.

The database is Huge (its the biggest out there), and there are tools available. And its free.

[Picard Tagger](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Picard_Tagger) is a cross platform tool for exactly what you are trying to do.

Technically there are a lot of different approaches. Especially in the Audio segment there are really a lot of methods. Most rely on frequency spectrum analysis. But also take into account Rythm, and developement of certain characteristics over time and of course trivial parameters like length etc.

Searching for audio fingerprinting should give you a lot of results.

Comment: i did find music brainz but it wasn't for linux afaik.  if this undertaking is the size its beginging to look like ill try and fallback to that

Comment: the source code should be available and written in python. just downlaod and compile... only pre compiled binaries are available for windows and mac

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this paper](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf) which details how the Shazam algorithm works.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the [Echo Nest](http://the.echonest.com/) [API](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/) for this sort of task. Their clientele are exactly app builders like you. It has a large database, is easy to use, and can retrieve the song information you want.

Answer (score 1):

did you consider [atunes](http://www.atunes.org/)?
the source code is at [source forge](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=161929) . can identify the song, written in Java.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly easy to understand article about this:

http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/how-does-shazam-recognize-song